# Sharepoint testing in Pester

Tags: unit-testing, sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0

I am currently working on some PowerShell script for SharePoint farm configuration (for example a script for SPWebapplication creation, User profile service application creation, MMS service application creation or search service application creation). My requirement is to test this module using Pester framework. I have very basic understanding about Pester. A sample code for web app creation is below:

```powershell
$webApplicationName = "A Name"

$hostingMainURL = "http://.....local"

$ContentDatabase = "Datacom_WebApp_ContentDB"
$applicationPoolDisplayName = "TestApppool"

$applicationPoolIdentity = (Get-SPManagedAccount "DEV\Apppool accountName")

$username = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name

$ap = New-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication

$applicationPoolDisplayName -ApplicationPoolAccount $applicationPoolIdentity -
Port 80 -AuthenticationProvider $ap -DatabaseName $ContentDatabase 

Write-Host "Set content database limits settings for $ContentDatabase..." -Foreground "green"

Set-SPContentDatabase -Identity $ContentDatabase -MaxSiteCount 1 -WarningSiteCount 0

New-SPSite -Url $hostingMainURL -owneralias $username -Name $webApplicationName -Description "Hosting root site collection"
```

I need a starting point from here. I need some advise on how I can create some test cases on Mocking for example:

- Mock `New-SPWebapplication`
- Mock `Get-SPManagedAccount`
- Mock `New-SPSite`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inModuleScope 'ModuleCallingSpWeb' {
function Get-SPWebApplication {}

Mock -ModuleName ModuleCallingSpWeb Get-SPWebApplication
}

Comment: Describe 'Calling SPManagedAccount' 
{
inModuleScope 'ModuleCallingSpWeb' 
  { 
    function Get-SPWebApplication {}
    It 'Calls Get-SPWebApplication' 
        {
        Mock -ModuleName ModuleCallingSpWeb Get-SPWebApplication
        } 
  }
}